Most simple config not working for locust
This command works fine
locust --headless --users 10 --spawn-rate 1 -H http://localhost:3000

locustfile.py looks like that
from locust import HttpUser, task


class HelloWorldUser(HttpUser):
    @task
    def hello_world(self):
        self.client.get("/health")

but putting the same code in a local.py and this to a local.conf
locustfile = local.py
headless = true
master = true
expect-workers = 3
host = "http://localhost:3000"
users = 3
spawn-rate = 1
run-time = 1m

that command runs but does not bring back any results
locust --config local.conf

any idea why ?

I can just tell you that it behaves the same way in both cases on my machine (I am no locust user, I get a bunsh of empty "Type, Name, #reqs, ... tables). Maybe try to deliberatly introduce errors? Point to a wrong .conf file, point to a wrong locustfile, do you get the appropriate error messages?

thanks but the command runs it just doesn't show metrics

Not sure what is causing the issue, but did you try running with the same parameters on command line as in config. expect-workers = 3 will make the process wait for 3 workers. Add the full output to the issue.

@Cyberwiz oh you could be right. Remowing that and master = true did run it but than complained not tasks for user

This minimal file did work. As I have used tags in the config file which did not exist in the local.py. Also the master and workers entry did expect distributed load infrastructure
locustfile = load_basics.py
headless = true
host = "http://localhost:50505"
users = 1
spawn-rate = 1
run-time = 1m

